# Setting Up Fabric SSH, Error:Timed Out

Tags: ssh, fabric, paramiko

I'm new to Fabric, so this might have a simple answer I've missed due to bad search terminology.

I'm trying to start a new ubuntu EC2 instance in AWS, then connect to it with Fabric and have it execute several commands. However, it seems there is a problem with Fabric's SSH connection, maybe I'm defining some env variable wrong?

```
@task    //starts new EC2 instance and sets env variables
def prep_deploy():
    //code to start new EC2 instance, named buildhost
    env.hosts=[buildhost.public_dns_name]
    env.user = "ubuntu"
    env.key_filename = ".../keypair.pem"
    env.port = 22

@task
def deploy():
    run("echo $HOME")  //code fails here
    ....
```

I run `fab prep_deploy deploy`, since I read you need a new task for the new env variables to take effect. 
I get 
`Fatal error: Timed out trying to connect to ...amazonaws.com (tried 1 time)`
`Underlying exception: timed out`

The security groups for the instance are open to SSH: I can connect through Putty. In fact, if I empty the `env.host_string' variable at the start of deploy(), when it prompts me to manually input a host, I can write in "ubuntu@...amazonaws.com:22", with the host name exactly as seen from output at the task start, and it will connect to the instance. But I can't figure how to manipulate the environment variables so that it understands the host name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your fabric settings are correct with the use of variables. I was able to use the code you provided to connect to my Ubuntu VM. I am wondering if you are having a connection issue due to the amazon Instance not being fully booted and ready for connections when your script runs the second task. I have run into that issue on a different VM hosts.
I added the following code to check and try the connection again. This might help you

```
import socket
import time

def waitforssh():
    s=socket.socket()
    address=env.host_string
    port=22
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        try:
            s.connect((address,port))
            return
        except Exception,e:
            print "failed to connec to %s:%s %(address,port)
            pass
```

insert the function call into your deploy task

```
def deploy():
    waitforssh()
```

This should test the connection. If the port does not respond, it will wait 5 seconds and try again.
That could explain why your second attempt to connect works.

Comment: I was doing something similar, using time(10) to wait until the instance state changes from "pending" to "running", but apparently that wasn't waiting quite long enough, as the waitforssh failed once before working. Thanks.

Comment: This might be another question, but now, while it does connect, it does not do so as user "ubuntu", so my instance just tells me `Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root"`. Still seems related to some environment problem, but looks like user is labeled pretty clearly....Same code

Comment: Does this error message occur only durring the waitforssh() or in your deploy() code as well?

Comment: The error message only occurs when running commands on the instance (AWS doesn't like it when you use root); the waitforssh just connects and disconnects, so doesn't receive any error from using root, though it appears the "address" variable, aka copied host_string, doesn't include "ubuntu@", so it probably isn't being registered

Comment: the code i added shouldn't actually make a connection, but just check that port 22 is available for connection.  Can you add print("Executing on %s as %s" % (env.host, env.user))    to your script in the deploy section

Comment: Ah, sorry, that works. There was an error in my commands later causing it, totally my fault. Thanks a ton! That timing error was killing me!

Comment: print "failed to connec to %s:%s %(address,port)

you need a double quote at the end of print statement.

Comment: You might want to review boto3 (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html). You can use it to launch your instance from within fabric and it has 'waiters' such as 'wait_until_running'.